# Rendering window on a ssh session

Tags: server, 20.04, ssh, xorg, opengl

I came to you with a request, I'm trying to get output in the window format out of a ssh session on a linux server, the setup is as follows:
Server Ubuntu 22.04 on a machine, ssh server on that, and a client Macbook m1 with which I operate, now I tried to run some graphics with OpenGL, but the rendering window doesn't show up, I get the following message: `Failed to create GLFW window`

I've came across X11; which is what you might have on a WSL session, but I haven't arrived at a workable solution yet.

Thank you